# SQL - populating table

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: Thanks guys. It was truly just a formatting error of the single-quotation mark from the source code I copied. Thanks a lot!

**Codes:**

```
USE Library;
INSERT INTO myLibrary VALUES (
    ‘SQL Bible’
    ,‘Alex Kriegel’
    ,‘Boris M. Trukhnov’
    ,‘Wiley’
    ,888
    ,‘April 7,2008’
    ,‘978-0470229064’
    ,‘English’
);
```

**Output:**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '‘'.
```

**Question**
What is the problem here? I am new to SQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need straight quotes : `'` for string literals, not those strange curly ones `‘`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, strings are defined with the `'` characters, not `‘` and `’`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the format at notepad++ and it works. The codes I copied seem to have different format of single-quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong character to encapsulate your strings. Instead of the `‘` character, you need to use either a `'` or a `"`:

```
USE Library;
INSERT INTO myLibrary VALUES (
    "SQL Bible"
    ,"Alex Kriegel"
    ,"Boris M. Trukhnov"
    ,"Wiley"
    ,888
    ,"April 7,2008"
    ,"978-0470229064"
    ,"English"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did a copy/paste from some software, like Word, it can have formatting attached. Your SQL engine will not interpret it.

Take the code, put it into notepad or some other simple text editor (notepad + or jedit are two that I use) and do a replace the open quote and the end quote with a ' or ".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the format at notepad++ and it works. The codes I copied seem to have different format of single-quotation mark.

Comment: If you're happy with the result, please check the box to show which answer worked for you.